# How to add multiple Google Maps API configs in a multi-flavor app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a multi-flavor Android app because I need my dev, qa and prod applications with different IDs to connect to different Firebase projects.

```
flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "env"
        applicationId "com.myapp.debug"
    }
    qa {
        dimension "env"
        applicationId "com.myapp.beta"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "env"
        applicationId "com.myapp"
    }
}
```

I also added 3 versions of google_maps_api.xml in the respective source folders like so:

[image]

In the dev version, everything works smoothly, the maps shows OK. But when I release the app in closed alpha after generating a signed version with the release/qa variant, the map doesn't show in the app.

Since I'm still a newbie in Android, I don't know what I might have missed or even how I can troubleshoot this issue? Is there an easy way to see the logs of the qa version released in closed alpha? Am I missing something obvious? Where should I find the google_maps_api.xml file in the signed APK, so that I can check that the right one is in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what I missed. I opted in to Google Play App signing, so I'm signing my app with an upload key, and then Google signs it with a deploy key that it keeps. And I found [this piece of documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), that says I have to get my SHA-1 fingerprint from Google and use this in my Google Maps API key. So I exported that SHA-1 and I pasted it into my Google Maps API key configuration and now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use different Maps API keys for different flavor as follow

Step 1: Add your different keys in manifestPlaceholders in app/build.gradle

```
  flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "default"
            manifestPlaceholders.google_maps_key = "Dev API key here"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            manifestPlaceholders.google_maps_key = "Staging API key here"
        }
    }
```

Step 2: In the AndroidManifest.xml inside the application tag use this code to refer API key as per the flavor

```
<application    
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="${google_maps_key}"/>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `google_maps_key` from `google_map_api.xml` file and declare it in gradle file as mentions below

```
flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "env"
            applicationId "com.myapp.debug"
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'google_maps_key_for_dev'  // update your actual key
        }
        qa {
            dimension "env"
            applicationId "com.myapp.beta"
              resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'google_maps_key_for_qa'  // update your actual key
        }
        prod {
            dimension "env"
            applicationId "com.myapp"
              resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'google_maps_key_for_prod' // update your actual key
        }
    }
```

You have to generate new map key for each applicationId.

Comment: I already have a different key for each applicationId. I will try adding them to the gradle build like you mentioned.

Comment: I tried added the google maps key to the gradle build file, but the result is the same: the map doesn't show, it's just gray. And I checked the logcat in Android studio for that app, with the phone connected to it, and it doesn't show any error message.

Comment: i think there is issue with sign certificate,you are generating apk with different signature ,for testing fresh install the apk,it will show error message in logcat for upload SHA with that SHA value